# Getting a list of available SQI servers

Tags: sql-server, qt, dsn

How can I get a list of available Sql servers (or instances?) On the local network (preferably hostname).
Approximately how it is done in the DSN data source settings:
picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADM6w.png

Comment: In PowerShell, `Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication]::EnumAvailableSqlServers()`. Results will depend on your network and firewall settings.

Comment: Okay, but how do I tie the result to the program? I'm writing on Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with Qt `QProcess`, and the windows command [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) .

> SQLCMD  -L[c]
>
> Lists the locally configured server computers, and the **names of the
>   server computers that are broadcasting on the network**. This
>   parameter cannot be used in combination with other parameters. The
>   maximum number of server computers that can be listed is 3000.

.h

```
#include <QProcess>

private slots:
    void readResult();
private:
    QProcess getSQLNodes;
```

.cpp

```
 getSQLNodes.setProgram("SQLCMD");
 getSQLNodes.setArguments({"-Lc"});
 getSQLNodes.start();
 getSQLNodes.waitForStarted();
 connect(&getSQLNodes,&QProcess::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readResult);

 void MainWindow::readResult()
 {
     while(getSQLNodes.bytesAvailable()){
     QString DSNservers =  getSQLNodes.readAll();
     qDebug() << DSNservers ;
     this->ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(DSNservers);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for!